# Run a very slow script til it succeeds

Tags: bash

My script `fetch_remote_work.sh` is quite slow because it connects to a network.
I need run it many times until it works.

```
./fetch_remote_work.sh

while [ $? -ne 0 ]
do
    ./fetch_remote_work.sh
done
```

This obviously works well. However, I don't like being obligated to call the first `./fetch_remote_work.sh`.
I know that in other languages such as [php](/questions/tagged/php), there is a *do while* loop that runs at least the first iteration. Which would be very clean if it existed in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

So my question is: is there a cleaner way than what I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command itself as conditional for the `while` construct.

`while ! ./fetch_remote_work.sh; do :; done`

Comment: Great! but this works `while [ ./fetch_remote_work.sh ]; do; done`, please update your answer

Comment: @smarber While Spidey's answer is semantically correct (although probably should be `while !`), your comment is not. `[ x ]` just checks that the string `x` is not empty, so your script is never run at all.

Comment: @ChrisDown `while !` works but `while ./fetch...` doesn't. However `while [ ./fetch_remote_work.sh ]` works too. To reproduce what I'm saying, you can create `fetch_remote_work.sh` with `exit 2` inside...

Comment: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'` -- you need some sort of command after your `do`, like a sleep or `:`

Comment: @JeffSchaller you're right!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run something *until* it has a zero return code,

```
until [ $RANDOM -eq 42 ]
do 
  echo looking for the answer to life, the universe, and everything
done
```

(or as a one-liner)

```
until [ $RANDOM -eq 42 ]; do echo looking for the answer to life, the universe, and everything; done
```

For your example:

```
until ./fetch_remote_work.sh; do :; done
```

This loop does "nothing" (execute the [`:` builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon)) *until* the fetch_remote_work.sh script returns 0.

Comment: Oh boy! New useful thing, I never heard of before, to learn `:` again .... thx!

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line to `false`, forcing the desirable condition for the first iteration.

Comment: It's makes it better, indeed. However it's not as perfect as `do while`

Comment: I'm thinking the actual question is "is there an equivalent to do-while in shell script?"

Comment: Maybe you're right, but if there is another way without even using a loop I'll take it

Comment: I don't understand why you're looking for a way "without a loop" when your question says "I need to run it many times until it works"

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, I'm just looking for a cleaner way than what I did, with or without loop, I don't care, that's why I don't talk about the technique in the title